# Post checked checkbox values that ate generated dynamically to php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysqli

I do have a table that is generated dynamically from MySQL table values. Each listed record has a checkbox.

list.php

```
$query="SELECT * FROM drivers ORDER BY name";
$query=$mysqli->query($query);
$queryN=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($queryN!=0){
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
       $id=$row['id'];
       $name=$row['name'];

       $output .='<tr id="'.$id.'">
                  <td>'.$name.'</td>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="assign" class="assigned" value='.$id.'"/></td>
                  </tr>';
  }
}else{
       $output .='<tr>
                  <td colspan="2">No data found</td>
                  </tr>';
}
```

The HTML file

```
<input type="button" name="send" id="send" value="Send" />
```

Now the JQuery script that will send only the values of the checked checkboxes in the table:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.send').click(function(){

        var checkValues = $('input[name=assign]:checked').map(function()
        {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'assigndriver.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { ids: checkValues },
            success:function(data){

            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Finally, the PHP file assigndriver.php that will insert the array with the values of only checked checkboxes:

```
   include "../connect_to_mysql.php";

   $id = array();

   if(isset($_POST['ids'])){

    $id  = $_POST['ids'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++) {
             $id_new = $id[$i];
             $sql="INSERT INTO teste (campo) VALUES ('$id_new')";    
        }     
    }
```

Well, I would like to know why it isn't working and if in this way the correct value of the checkbox, that must be the variable $id is being posted correctly to the PHP file.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try to change:

```
$('.send').click(
```

to:

```
$('#send').click(
```

since you assign `id="send"` not `class="send"` to your input button

Comment: Thanks! I did the change but still not posting values!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the name of the checkbox as name="something[]". So it will know it is an array and values will posted correctly. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry guys! Still not working. No value has been inserted to the database.

Answer (score 0):

In the jquery you call the send button using id **send** but while calling the function   you use **.** operator insted of **#** operator.

**Difference**

```
  the difference between "." operator and "#" operator is when you calling a 
  class you should use "."  operator.

  Example:
          HTML:
               <input type="button" name="send" class="send" value="Send" />  

         JQUERY:
                $('.send').click(function(){

                     //insert your code here..
                });


  but if you are going to call an id of a html element than use "#" operetor  

  Example: 
          HTML:
               <input type="button" name="send" id="send" value="Send" 
                onclick="send_data();" />



         JQUERY:
                 function send_data(){
                 $('#send').click(function(){

                     //insert your code here..
                });}
```

Hope it will help you...

Comment: Even replacing the class with id="send" and $("#send").click(... the values still cannot be posted and inserted to the database.

Comment: ok change your LIST.PHP code  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) to  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))...hope it will work.If its work vote the post ...hav fun

Comment: Did you get the result?

Comment: in assigndriver.php code call the mysql_query($sql); it will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

The right way to make the values of each checked checkbox be posted to the PHP file is doing the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnadd').click(function(){

        var checkValues = $('input[name="assign[]"]:checked').map(function()
        {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'assigndriver.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { ids: checkValues },
            success:function(data){

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also, we need to change the dynamic output in the PHP file:

```
$output .='<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="assign[]" id="add_driver'.$id.'" value="'.$id.'"/></td>';
```

If the checkbox is checked, the values will be posted correctly.